# How to globally import react-native style classes

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-ios

Ni, I'm using a react component, in my react-native app. It transitioned over to react-native fine, except for styling. This is how the component is rendered:

```
<Leaderboard
    data={this.state.sampleData}
    votes="score"
    artistName="artist"
    songTitle="name"
    albumCover="image"
    id="id"
/>
```

It uses the following style sheet when running in web:
`import "react-h5-audio-player/lib/styles.css";`

Unfortunately, react-native doesn't accept .css files. So I created the following styles.js file:

```
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rhap_container: {
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    lineHeight: "1",
    fontFamily: "inherit",
    width: "100%",
    padding: "10px 15px",
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    boxShadow: "0 0 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
  },
  rhap_container_focus_not__focus_visible: {
    outline: "0",
  },
  rhap_container_svg: {
    verticalAlign: "initial",
  },
  rhap_header: {
    marginBottom: "10px",
  },...
```

I'm stuck now: how do I import this new styles object, so it applies to Leaderboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to export your styles in `styles.js` by adding `export default`

Now you can import it in Leaderboard component, into `Leaderboard.js` directly or passing styles to its props like this :

```
import styles from "./styles.js";

<Leaderboard
    data={this.state.sampleData}
    votes="score"
    artistName="artist"
    songTitle="name"
    albumCover="image"
    id="id"
    style={styles.rhap_container} // or you could pass all styles styles={styles}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Where do I add the export default? When I do ```export default styles = StyleSheet.create({``` it says "styles is not defined"

Comment: You can export a const. 
`export default const styles = StyleSheet.create({ `

I recommend you to read also documentation about stylesheet, their also other options in RN styling :
 https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet